# php mysqli query select

Tags: php, mysqli

I have 3 different tables
table 1 keep general scores over the year
table 2 and 3 is event specific
only common field in all 3 is a member ID

I need to select 5 top score results for each member from table1 combine them with 1 specific result from table 2 and 3
I managed to get everything together in a temp table, but cnt get the output the way I need it 
example what i have and need.

[image]

Original code
`$prevQuery = "SELECT distinct member_id FROM scores";`
`$prevResult = $conn->query($prevQuery);`
`while($row = $prevResult->fetch_assoc()) {`
`$scores=("SELECT member_id,event_id,event_date,event_score FROM scores where member_id = ".$id." ORDER BY event_score DESC LIMIT 5");`

Comment: why don't you do this in your presentation layer .

Comment: do you want the 5 highest scores from each member or the 5 highest scoring members?

Comment: already got the top 5 scores for each member using following ("INSERT INTO temp_score (member_id,event_location,event_date,event_score) SELECT member_id,event_location,event_date,event_score FROM scores where member_id = ".$id." ORDER BY event_score DESC LIMIT 5"); - Now I need to display the location , date and the top 5 scores for each member, output need to be displayed as in the bottom of image

Comment: why not just select the top 5 scores and display it like that using PHP?

Comment: Excatly what i try do do.
I did select the top 5 scores from the database table which result in giving me the 5 scores for the member
the result display as 5 outputs with no destict value for each member
I need to display only the member ID(name) once with the dates and scores next to it

member name | score date 1| score 1 | score date 2| scoreJohn      
member name | score date 1| score 1 | score date 2| scoreSarah

Comment: This question would be better if it had your existing code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Query:**

```
select * from temp_table order by mem_id asc
```

**PHP:**

you can simple do your expected result in your application like this

```
<?php   
$result = array(array('mem_id'=>1,'location'=>'A','date'=>'20/05/2017','score'=>100),array('mem_id'=>1,'location'=>'B','date'=>'21/05/2017','score'=>103),array('mem_id'=>1,'location'=>'C','date'=>'22/05/2017','score'=>106),array('mem_id'=>1,'location'=>'C','date'=>'23/05/2017','score'=>108),
                array('mem_id'=>2,'location'=>'A','date'=>'20/05/2017','score'=>105),array('mem_id'=>2,'location'=>'B','date'=>'21/05/2017','score'=>109),array('mem_id'=>2,'location'=>'C','date'=>'22/05/2017','score'=>111),array('mem_id'=>2,'location'=>'C','date'=>'23/05/2017','score'=>110));

$new_result=array();
foreach($result as $key=>$row)
{

    $new_result[$row['mem_id']][]=$row;
}

echo "<table border='1px'>";
echo "<thead><tr><th>S.No</th><th>date</th><th>score1</th><th>date</th><th>score2</th><th>date</th><th>score3</th><th>date</th><th>score4</th></tr>";
echo "<tbody>";
foreach($new_result as $key=>$row)
{

    echo "<tr><td>".$key."</td>";
    foreach($row as $key1=>$row1)
    {
        echo "<td>".$row1['date']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row1['score']."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</tbody>"; 
echo "</table>";
?>
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
S.No    date    score1  date    score2  date    score3  date    score4
1   20/05/2017  100 21/05/2017  103 22/05/2017  106 23/05/2017  108
2   20/05/2017  105 21/05/2017  109 22/05/2017  111 23/05/2017  110
```

Comment: TX think it will help, just need to add the values then from the datbase to the array

Comment: yes ofcourse  .if my answer is useful mark it with green tick it's useful for future user reference @TheWizard

Comment: Will do, give me 10 min and i will have feedback